Setting value of left var doesn't show in transition animation


let elem = document.querySelector(".e")
let but1 = document.querySelector(".but1")
let but2 = document.querySelector(".but2")
but1.addEventListener("click", () => {
  elem.style.setProperty("--x", `300px`)
})
but2.addEventListener("click", () => {
  elem.style.setProperty("--x", `500px`)
})
.e {
  top: 50px;
  left: calc(var(--x));
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: black;
  transition: 2000ms ease-in-out;
}
<div class="e">2</div>
<button class="but1">click me</button>
<button class="but2">click me</button>



When I click but1, it sets the value of variable x and moves right to the distance as the value. But it doesn't play the transition animation. In subsequent clicks of button 1 and button 2 it does show the animation. Why?

The reason the animation is not executed on the first click is because the CSS variable --x initially has no value.
When you click the button for the first time, the variable is set for the first time. The animation will not play because there is no starting value for the transition.
On the second and subsequent clicks, --x is already set and there is a starting value, so the transition works correctly.
To ensure that the animation is executed on the first click, you can add a fallback option for the --x variable so that there is a starting value from which the transition is executed.
Remove the unnecessary calc. It doesn't calculate anything. Set a fallback for the variable. For example, set 0 as a fallback.
left: var(--x, 0);



let elem = document.querySelector(".e")
let but1 = document.querySelector(".but1")
let but2 = document.querySelector(".but2")
but1.addEventListener("click", () => {
  elem.style.setProperty("--x", `300px`)
})
but2.addEventListener("click", () => {
  elem.style.setProperty("--x", `500px`)
})
.e {
  top: 50px;
  left: var(--x, 0);
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: black;
  transition: 2000ms ease-in-out;
}
<div class="e">2</div>
<button class="but1">click me</button>
<button class="but2">click me</button>




still it doesnt answer my question. why it is not running transition animation on the first time?

This is exactly the answer to your question
